# I am unable to parse and load a nested JSON file into postgres with Python3

Tags: json, python-3.x, postgresql, nested

I have tried everything in my power the past week to try and load a JSON file into Postgres table via python 3. it is a nested JSON and while I was able to follow through a few basic examples, I am just unable to code this correctly. My **ado.json** file is like this. Ultimately I just want to flatten this thing.

I keep getting this error:

```
xecute_sql() error: syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 2: VALUES ('System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy', {'linkType': 'System.L...
```

I am really new to python and just learning this on the fly. It appears the way I am calling the list is only reading 2 columns (rel & attributes). I have read through dozens on blogs, but unfortunately I am unable to follow through correctly.

```
[
    {
        "rel":"System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy","attributes":{"linkType":"System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward","sourceId":13,"targetId":23,"isActive":true,"changedDate":"2019-01-18T18:45:53.013Z","changedBy":{"id":"3209f8e3-95a2-6448-a146-13e374bd03bc","displayName":"Stacey Clark","uniqueName":"Clark_Stacey@gaaf.com","descriptor":"aad.MzIwOWY4ZTMtOTVhMi03NDQ4LWExNDYtMTNlMzc0YmQwM2Jj"},"comment":null,"changedOperation":"create","sourceProjectId":"7dc32e0c-84d4-46a4-aec6-1f0a22b60ef8","targetProjectId":"7dc32e0c-84d4-46a4-aec6-1f0a22b60ef8"}
    },
    {
        "rel":"System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy","attributes":{"linkType":"System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward","sourceId":9,"targetId":24,"isActive":true,"changedDate":"2019-01-18T18:46:08.64Z","changedBy":{"id":"3209f8e3-95a2-6448-a146-13e374bd03bc","displayName":"Stacey Clark","uniqueName":"Clark_Stacey@gaaf.com","descriptor":"aad.MzIwOWY4ZTMtOTVhMi03NDQ4LWExNDYtMTNlMzc0YmQwM2Jj"},"comment":null,"changedOperation":"create","sourceProjectId":"7dc32e0c-84d4-46a4-aec6-1f0a22b60ef8","targetProjectId":"7dc32e0c-84d4-46a4-aec6-1f0a22b60ef8"}
    },
    {
        "rel":"System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy","attributes":{"linkType":"System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward","sourceId":9,"targetId":25,"isActive":true,"changedDate":"2019-01-18T18:46:26.64Z","changedBy":{"id":"3209f8e3-95a2-6448-a146-13e374bd03bc","displayName":"Stacey Clark","uniqueName":"Clark_Stacey@gaaf.com","descriptor":"aad.MzIwOWY4ZTMtOTVhMi03NDQ4LWExNDYtMTNlMzc0YmQwM2Jj"},"comment":null,"changedOperation":"create","sourceProjectId":"7dc32e0c-84d4-46a4-aec6-1f0a22b60ef8","targetProjectId":"7dc32e0c-84d4-46a4-aec6-1f0a22b60ef8"}
    }
]
```

the Python script I am using is below.

```
import json, sys  # Import Python's built-in JSON Library
import pandas as pd
import flatten_json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from psycopg2 import connect, Error # import the psycopg2 database adapter for PostgreSQL

# use Python's open() function to load the JSON data
with open('ado.json', encoding='utf-8') as json_data:
    record_list = json.loads(json_data.read())
    print(record_list)

if type(record_list) == list:
    first_record = record_list[0]

    # I am unable to get the correct column names. only rel and attributes show up

    columns = list(first_record.keys())
    print ("\ncolumn names:", columns)

table_name = "json_data_ado"
sql_string = 'INSERT INTO {} '.format( table_name )
sql_string += "(" + ', '.join(columns) + ")\nVALUES "

for i, record_dict in enumerate(record_list):

    values = []
    for col_names, val in record_dict.items():

        # Postgres strings must be enclosed with single quotes
        if type(val) == str:
            val = val.replace("'", "''")
            val = "'" + val + "'"

        values += [ str(val) ]
    # join the list of values and enclose record in parenthesis
    sql_string += "(" + ', '.join(values) + "),\n"

# remove the last comma and end statement with a semicolon
sql_string = sql_string[:-2] + ";"

##insert json data into postgres sql  -- Simply output to screen
print ("\nSQL statement:")
print (sql_string)

# Connect to postgres
try:
    # declare a new PostgreSQL connection object
    conn = connect(
        dbname = "postgres",
        user = "postgres",
        host = "test.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
        password = "postgres",
        # attempt to connect for 3 seconds then raise exception
        connect_timeout = 10
    )

    cur = conn.cursor()
    print ("\ncreated cursor object:", cur)

except (Exception, Error) as err:
    print ("\npsycopg2 connect error:", err)
    conn = None
    cur = None

if cur != None:

    try:
        cur.execute( sql_string )
        conn.commit()

        print ('\nfinished INSERT INTO execution')

    except (Exception, Error) as error:
        print("\nexecute_sql() error:", error)
        conn.rollback()

    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: [Use bind parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html), not string concatenation, to put values into SQL queries. Then all that conversion code goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add values to SQL queries using string concatenation. As you've discovered, escaping the values properly is complicated and can lead to bugs and [security holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Instead, [use bind parameters to pass your values into the SQL query like you would a function](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). No escaping is necessary.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)", (100, "abc'def"))
```

You do need to set up the placeholders, similar to how you're setting up the columns.

```
# insert into json_data_ado (foo, bar) values (%s, %s)
sql_string = 'insert into json_data_ado'
sql_string += "(" + ', '.join(columns) + ")\n"
sql_string += "values (" + ", ".join(["%s" for x in columns]) + ")\n"
```

Then simply pass the list of values into execute. They will slot into the `%s` placeholders.

```
cur.execute(sql_string, values)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I modified the script as follows:

Comment: I am unable to follow this. I have tried both methods for cursor execute as you have mentioned. I get this error ```execute_sql() error: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 3: ('System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy', {'linkType': 'System.LinkType...```

Comment: @piffer It's hard to tell what might be wrong from just snippets of code, but note the error is at `(` which means there's something quite wrong with the query. And note `{'linkType': ...` which means you're trying to pass in a stringified Python dictionary, not JSON. This is because you're inserting the values in each dictionary, but the value of `attributes` is another dictionary. You'll have to disassemble the original complex structure into a simple list of strings and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback. I modified according to your feedback the two section as below. But now get an error about the syntax %s.

My generated SQL statement is like below. However there are more columns in my Json, so I am not sure why only 2 columns "rel and attributes" show in the column names. I tried parse the columns like this.

```
with open('ado.json', encoding='utf-8') as json_data:
    record_list = json.loads(json_data.read())
    print(record_list)

if type(record_list) == list:
    first_record = record_list[0]

    columns = list(first_record.keys())
    print ("\ncolumn names:", columns)
```

```
column names: ['rel', 'attributes']

SQL statement:
insert into json_data_ado(rel, attributes)
values (%s, %s)
('System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy', {'linkType': 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward', 'sourceId': 13, 'targetId': 23, 'isActive': True, 'changedDate': '2019-01-18T18:45:53.013Z', 'changedBy': {'id': '3209f8e3-95a2-6448-a146-13e374bd03bc', 'displayName': 'Stacey Clark', 'uniqueName': 'Clark_Stacey@test.com', 'descriptor': 'aad.MzIwOWY4ZTMtOTVhMi03NDQ4LWExNDYtMTNlMzc0YmQwM2Jj'}, 'comment': None, 'changedOperation': 'create', 'sourceProjectId': '7dc32e0c-84d4-46a4-aec6-1f0a22b60ef8', 'targetProjectId': '7dc32e0c-84d4-46a4-aec6-1f0a22b60ef8'}),
('System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy', {'linkType': 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward', 'sourceId': 9, 'targetId': 24, 'isActive': True, 'changedDate': '2019-01-18T18:46:08.64Z', 'changedBy': {'id': '3209f8e3-95a2-6448-a146-13e374bd03bc', 'displayName': 'Stacey Clark', 'uniqueName': 'Clark_Stacey@test.com', 'descriptor': 'aad.MzIwOWY4ZTMtOTVhMi03NDQ4LWExNDYtMTNlMzc0YmQwM2Jj'}, 'comment': None, 'changedOperation': 'create', 'sourceProjectId': '7dc32e0c-84d4-46a4-aec6-1f0a22b60ef8', 'targetProjectId': '7dc32e0c-84d4-46a4-aec6-1f0a22b60ef8'}),
```

```
try:
        cur.execute("""Insert into json_data_ado (rel, attributes ,linktype , source1d , targetid , isactive , changeddate , changedby ,id ,displayname ,uniquename ,descriptor ,comment , changedoperation ,sourceprojectid , targetprojectid  )
        values (%s, %s, %s, %s,  %s, %s, %s, %s,  %s, %s, %s, %s,  %s, %s, %s, %s )""")
        conn.commit()
```

and

```
# insert into json_data_ado (foo, bar) values (%s, %s)
sql_string = 'insert into json_data_ado'
sql_string += "(" + ', '.join(columns) + ")\n"
sql_string += "values (" + ", ".join(["%s" for x in columns]) + ")\n"
```

I get this error about the syntax

```
execute_sql() error: syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 2:         values (%s, %s, %s, %s,  %s, %s, %s, %s,  %s, %s, %s...
```

Comment: You have to pass the values into `execute` which fill in all those `%s`.